# PHP result how to pass ajax success function

Tags: php, ajax

I'm not getting success message from ajax which I called in success function.
Please check the code of my **index.php**, **contact-form-script.js** and **form-process.php**

```
 $("#contactForm").validator().on("submit", function (event) {
    if (event.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        // handle the invalid form...
        formError();
        submitMSG(false, "Did you fill in the form properly?");
    } else {
        // everything looks good!
        event.preventDefault();
        submitForm();
    }
});

function submitForm(){
    // Initiate Variables With Form Content
    var name = $("#sugname").val()
    var email = $("#sugemail").val();
    var mobile = $("#sugmobile").val();
    var message = $("#sugmessage").val();


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "form-process.php",

        data: "name=" + name + "&email=" + email + "&mobile=" + mobile + "&message=" + message,
        success : function(text){
            if (text == "success"){
                formSuccess();
            } else {
                formError();
                submitMSG(false,text);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: alert `text` and check what you get from server.

Comment: what does `formSuccess();` this do ,also did you got response from ajax or not ?

Comment: alert(text); nothing to display anything

Comment: function formSuccess(){
    $("#contactForm")[0].reset();
    submitMSG(true, "Message Submitted!");
}

Comment: post your `form-process.php` code as well

Comment: I tried your code, your success msg is based on the condition you get the string "success" in response. I would suggest put console.log or alert in else condition to check what are you exactly getting in response. also since you're not using json "success " with a space will also not work

Answer (score 0):

Do changes like below in your code :

```
 //if errormsg not empty 
 if(!empty($errorMSG)){
  //print 
  echo $errorMSG;
 }else{
  //execute query
  include('dbconfig.php');
  $sql="insert into suggestions(name,contactno,mailid,jfsuggestion) values 
  ('".$name."','".$mobile."','".$email."','".$message."')";
  $success = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  if($success){
  echo "success";
  }
 }
```

Comment: didn't work. thanks for changes. but First time I run my code, PHP echo success displayed me instead of Message Submitted! .. simple echo statement also not displaying now.. Data inserted in db. message only not displaying

Comment: okay remove `if($success){
  echo "success";
  }` and only put there `echo "success";` and see what does that gives ,also edit your question with changes made in your code.

Comment: I tried, echo or print not working in this page.. any idea

Comment: under your ajax `success` function do `alert("something");` check if this alert shows up when you run your php code,also i don't know if this is the issue but , near `success` there is little space `success:` remove that space between `success` and `:` .

Comment: alert(text); is now working. my php echo "success" displayed in alert. but not  working in my condition. y? my condition: if (text == "success"){
                formSuccess();
            } else {
                formError();
                submitMSG(false,text);
            }

Comment: check like this-->`if($.trim(text)==="success"){ formSuccess(); } else { formError(); submitMSG(false,text); }`

Comment: glad i helped , try to accept this answer if it help you .